# php - float value with two decimal places

Tags: php, types, floating-point

Is there any way in PHP to have a float value (not a string) with two decimal places if these are zeroes?

Example:

```
$v = 1.50
```

Using `(float)` or `floatval($v)` would return the number as `1.5`

I get that I can use `number_format()` for an arbitrary precision, but that would return a string, and once I cast it to a float, I hit the same problem.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to consider a floating-point number as having more decimal places than it needs. It would still be the exact same value. It only makes sense when you are talking about displaying it somewhere. That's what `number_format()` is for.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would need to do, display it somewhere, as a float

Comment: you can use `round()` [http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php)

Comment: same result, I guess there's no way around it

Comment: @miglio `round()` returns a `float`, so it wouldn't make any difference. `round(1.5, 2)` would still produce `1.5`

Comment: @mikeyq6 , you have reason, but it could be like`sprintf('%0.2f', round(1.5, 2)); `

Comment: @miglio `sprintf('%0.2f', round(1.5, 2));` would produce exactly the same thing as `sprintf('%0.2f', 1.5);`, so it's pointless to have the `round()` at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. The variable (as a `float`) contains just the datum and `1.5` or `1.50` is just the same thing and internally it's stored as a [floating point number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

You can see the value printed as `1.5` or `1.50` only when it's converted to a string, explicitly (using `number_format()`) or implicitly (printing directly the variable or inspecting the value in the debugger). You're supposed to use `number_format()` when you want to write the value as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the infos

Answer (score 1):

This may be help you :

Example:

```
$foo = "105";

echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00
```

Comment: that returns a string

Answer (score 0):

this is another way:

```
$num = 1.2;
$dec = 2;
echo sprintf('%0.'.$dec.'f', round($num, $dec));
```

response:

1.20

Comment: that's the same as sprintf('%.2f', $num);
and it returns a string

Comment: @Carlo round go inner sprintf like sample `sprintf('%.2f', round($num, 2))`